# What is that <E> in the method signature?

Tags: java, generics, collections, set, linkedhashset

I was reading about Set interface from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) which the code sipped below which is a generic method that removes duplicates from a collection.

My question is what is that `**< E>**` placed after static before `Set<E>` ?

I mean wouldn't that  `Set<E>` be enough ? why `<E>` was there twice?

```
public static <E> Set<E> removeDups(Collection<E> c) {
    return new LinkedHashSet<E>(c);
}
```

Comment: In the same tutorial, you can read it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: I went and read it but didnt get the relevance!

Comment: Read [*Generic Types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: You're lucky. When I get to the same confusion and asked here I got downvoted. And yes the answer is in the Generic Method section of the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

This means that this method declares a generic parameter type which the class does not define; in this case, you MUST declare the parameter type before the return type (even if this "return type" is `void`).

---

Think about it this way. Remove the initial `<E>`. Your declaration would then become:

```
public static Set<E> removeDups(Collection<E> c)
```

What is `E` here? Unless it is a generic parameter type defined by the class itself, it can only be an existing class.

Hence this syntax. It allows you to define a generic parameter for use in the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Here `**<E>**` is a generic type. Generic type is defined as

> A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized
>   over types. The following Box class will be modified to demonstrate
>   the concept. [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

And regarding you question related to `<E>`. A good description for it can be found on the same tutorial

**Type Parameter Naming Conventions**

> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters.
>   This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that
>   you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention,
>   it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable
>   and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:

```
 E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
    K - Key
    N - Number
    T - Type
    V - Value
    S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

> You'll see these names used throughout the Java SE API and the rest of
>   this lesson.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the generic type used within the method. Static methods that use generic types must specify that type before the return type.